# How to avoid copying my files from itunes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, itunes, ipod

Can any one get me how to restrict to copy the ipa files from itunes to mac, and restrict copying the files inside the documents or other folders .

So that the hackers cant get the documents inside the application. There is any secure way to restrict.

Comment: "restrict to copy the ipa files from itunes to mac" You cant do that !

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do that, because if hackers want to do something they will do ;) So I think you can protect your application by licence.